# Is PowerBuilder 9 compatible with Office 2010

Tags: powerbuilder

I have a PowerBuilder 9 application that worked fine with Word 2003 when I created a Word oleobject. We installed Office 2010 on a newer server and ported the application to it but
the Word documents that I try to open fail with an error of 35. Could this be a compatibility issue?

Comment: I use PowerBuilder 12 Classic to create documents using oleobject with Word 2007 and it works fine. Can't comment on PB 9/Word 2010.

Answer (score 1):

My experience is that compatibility has less to do with the PowerBuilder version, and more to do with subtle changes in the OLE API that Microsoft slips into Office between versions. I'd suggest going through your OLE code and re-researching them under the new Office to make sure they haven't been obsoleted.

Good luck,

Terry.

Comment: I got an answer that had to do with word.document for 2010 taking too long to start up and the timeout caused an error 35. Microsoft has a fix that we downloaded to our servers and that caused the issue to be resolved.

Comment: Would you please give the KB number for this. I have a user who seems to have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - PB9 came out about 6 years before Office 2010 was released.  They're not compatible.

You need to upgrade to a release past PB10...

Comment: We can't. Internal issues are making this an impossibility but we solved our error 35 problem with a download from Microsoft. Thanks for the advice, though.

Answer (score 0):

I probably phrased my question incorrectly. I was able previously to use Office 2003 with PB9 and had not problems opening documents. When the servers got Office 2010 installed, we got buried with error 35's and could not function without putting large delays into the code. The download from Microsoft did the trick and we are using Office 2010.

Comment: Can you please post the url of the Microsoft fix?

Answer (score 0):

I have PB code back from 6.5 that did some really trick OLE stuff with Excel.  Never changed that code (if I recall correctly).

Still works great with PB 12 and Office 2013.

YMMV